# Relationship between dimension and measures

Tags: ssas, olap, measure, dimension

There is a Fact Table (.....,MenuID, MOption, CallTime)
There is also a Dimension "Menu" Table (MenuId,OptionID)

Relationship between these tables (MenuID and MOption)

In the Dimension table, I created another field - keyField (string(MenuID+MOption) as OptionId2)

when creating Dimension, I use the new key (OptionId2) and build the hierarchy accordingly

- MenuId
- OptionId2(key)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2xox.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQxfJ.png)

but when I build a table with the Menu in the browser, my "Measures.CallTime" remains a constant number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYbyr.png)

What am I doing wrong?

The Dimension Menu should work like any other Dimension in the cube

For example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUChQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where my mistake was
In the Cube, the Dimension Usage partition was not linked

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fLGE.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).